# Inward spiral algorithm not working

Tags: c#, algorithm, spiral

I have this c# code to iterate through a grid in an inward spiral like this:

```
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5
```

Here is the code, but there is something wrong with it, for some reason it is taking much longer than expected to compute. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
    static void create_spiral_img(int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int size = width * height;
        int max = size;
        int count = 1;
        int i, j;
        while (size > 0)
        {
            for (i = y; i <= y + size - 1; i++)
            {
                draw_pixel(count++, x, i, graph);
            }

            for (j = x + 1; j <= x + size - 1; j++)
            {
                draw_pixel(count++, j, y + size - 1, graph);
            }

            for (i = y + size - 2; i >= y; i--)
            {
                draw_pixel(count++, x + size - 1, i, graph);
            }

            for (i = x + size - 2; i >= x + 1; i--)
            {
                draw_pixel(count++, i, y, graph);
            }

            x = x + 1;
            y = y + 1;
            size = size - 2;
            Console.Write(100 * ((float)(count) / (float)max) + "% ");
        }

        graph.Dispose();
        img.Save("./" + width + "x" + height + "_spiril.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        img.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: There are a few hundred console writes. I assume it might hurt...

Comment: If you are creating this to hypnotize people, there are much easier ways...  All kidding aside, how quickly are you expecting this to execute?

Comment: How fast is `draw_pixel`?

Comment: @Jon Dvorak: The drawpixel should be pretty fast, I have the same algorithm that iterates through a grid in a normal way (not spirally) yet that takes much less time.

Comment: @Brian: How can I re-write this in a much better way?

Comment: @Jon Dvorak: You only have size/2 Console.Write operations, not hundreds (unless the size is in the hundreds).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a square (width=height) it looks like you've got an O(x^4) implementation - that's going to be hideously slow.

I would recommend trying to drop it down to O(x^2).  Instead of drawing it spirally, rewrite your algorithm to draw it rectangularly - that is, go by rows & columns, calculating what each pixel should be.

Comment: Actually it doesn't have to be width=height, they can be different. Can you show me how to do this in O(n^2) with code?

Comment: It isn't O^4 - you might have four loops, but you are in essence still only doing height * width number of operations. So it is really o^2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
draw_pixel(c,x,y,g)
```

draws a point in color c at (x,y) coordinates in the graph g, you're going way too far. You're  doing

```
for (i = y; i <= y + size - 1; i++)
```

to print a line that should have length width, but you're printing a line of length size.

I'm thinking I didn't understand your algorithm. If this doesn't make sense, can you explain the semantics of draw_pixel please ?

Comment: Actually, the `draw_pixel` code isn't relevant, I'm mostly interesting in fixing the loops, so it iterates through a grid in a spiral pattern. Each (x,y) coordinate should only be iterated once.
The parameters of the `draw_pixel` is `draw_pixel(i, x, y, graph);`. The i and graph isn't relevant in my question.

Comment: Also you seem to have found a problem, but I don't understand, can you explain more?